# ERROR: type mismatch - how to persist with hibernate a bi-directional OneToOne mapping using spring-mvc forms

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

My way of coding this ends up in type mismatch as I am using JSP to assign value. (**Edit**: Type mismatch on `applicant_id`)

The use case is simple:
 *When on 'invite applicant' screen, the user should be able to select time and date and submit the form, which would assign the set time, date, to the applicant and vice versa.*

> Main Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/manageApplicant/invite")
public String inviteScreen(@RequestParam(value="id") int id, Model theModel) {
    theModel.addAttribute("interview", new Interview());
    Applicant applicants = mainService.getSpecificApplicant(id);
    theModel.addAttribute("applicants", applicants);
    return "invite-applicant";
}
```

> Interview class variable declaration

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="applicant_id", nullable=false)
private Applicant applicant_id;
```

> Applicant class variable declaration

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="interview_id")
private Interview interview_id;
```

> .JSP

```
<form:form action="/management/recruitment/setInterview" modelAttribute="interview">
<form:hidden path="applicant_id" value="${applicants}"/>
Date<form:input type="DATE" path="interviewDate"/><br>
Time<form:input type="TIME" path="interviewTime"/>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Invite for interview" id="submitButton" />
</form:form>
```

> MySQL TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE interviews(
id INT auto_increment NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id),
applicant_id int(11),
interviewDate date,
interviewTime time,
CONSTRAINT `FK_Applicant` FOREIGN KEY (`applicant_id`)
REFERENCES `applicant` (`id`)
);

ALTER TABLE applicant ADD 
CONSTRAINT `interviews_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`interview_id`)
REFERENCES `interviews` (`id`);
```

> Interview DAO implementation

```
public void saveInterview(Interview theInterview) {
    // get current session
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    // save interview
    currentSession.save(theInterview);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `@JoinColumn` and ForeignKey on both sides. The Interview contains the Applicant_id and this should be enough. If you want the association to be Bi-Directional you should tell JPA by which this field is mapped on the other side.

```
@OneToOne(mappedby="applicant_id")
private Interview interview_id;
```

Comment: Whilst you are correct on this. It is not the question I asked.